# Oracle correctly getting the month difference

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Hi Ive been having an issue with getting the correct difference in a date from the current month not including the day.

ie if the month when the query is run is march 2013

then the following should be the result

```
EXECUTION_DATE, EXEC_DIFF
01-FEB-13,  1
31-JAN-13,  2
30-JAN-13,  2
```

however using the below sql statement im getting

```
EXECUTION_DATE, EXEC_DIFF
01-FEB-13,  1
31-JAN-13,  2
30-JAN-13,  1
```

```
select EXECUTION_DATE,
       floor(MONTHS_BETWEEN (trunc(sysdate,'MM')-1, EXECUTION_DATE))+1 "EXEC_DIFF"
from V_CERT_LIST  
WHERE EXECUTION_DATE < TO_DATE('02/02/2013','DD/MM/YYYY') 
ORDER BY EXECUTION_DATE DESC
```

Please can someone put me right ive  been bashing my head with this for some time now

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select EXECUTION_DATE,
       MONTHS_BETWEEN (trunc(sysdate,'MM'), trunc(EXECUTION_DATE,'MM')) "EXEC_DIFF"
from V_CERT_LIST  
WHERE EXECUTION_DATE < TO_DATE('02/02/2013','DD/MM/YYYY') 
ORDER BY EXECUTION_DATE DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Not looking for scores but cannot understand what is the problem with months_between? In my understanding it does not matter when in month execution takes place - Jan-31 or Jan 30... The difference is still 2 months between Jan and Mar as in your example. I can add more days in month in the query but mo_betw. will still be the same...:

```
SELECT to_char(exec_date, 'DD-MON-YYYY') exec_date, MONTHS_BETWEEN(run_date, exec_date) months_btwn
 FROM
 (
 SELECT to_date('01/03/2013', 'DD/MM/YYYY') run_date
     , Add_Months(Trunc(sysdate,'YEAR'),Level-1) exec_date -- first day of each month
   FROM dual
 CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 3
 )
/


EXEC_DATE   MONTHS_BTWN
------------------------
 01-JAN-2013    2
 01-FEB-2013    1
 01-MAR-2013    0
```

Answer (score 0):

`Months_Between` has complex logic that takes the day of the month into account.

Perhaps what you want is this:

```
select EXECUTION_DATE,
       ((year(sysdate)*12+month(sysdate)) - (year(execution_date)*12 + month(execution_date))
       ) as Exec_Diff
from V_CERT_LIST  
WHERE EXECUTION_DATE < TO_DATE('02/02/2013','DD/MM/YYYY') 
ORDER BY EXECUTION_DATE DESC
```

This converts the year/month combination into the number of months since 0 time and then subtracts the results.